# mantener el formato html al guardar mis arhcivos con .php

Tags: formato

Tengo instalado  visual estudio code y cuando guardo mis archivos html con .php  se queda sin formato html
sólo en blanco no se diferenia nada.¿cómo pudeo solucionar ese problema . lo que quiero es que al guardar con extensión .php no pierda el formato html .

Answer (score 0):

Debes habilitar o en caso de que no tengas, instalar extenciones para que apliquen en ese formato.
Para la primera opcion te vas a archivo despues a preferencia y por ultimo a configuracion, de ahi buscas la pestaña extenciones y habilitas las de php.
En otro caso solo te vas a extensiones y buscas que mas te agrade.